# jQuery animate to center of elements with varying widths

Tags: jquery, width, jquery-animate, response, center

I have been messing around with this all morning, I know little to nothing about jQuery...apologies.

I have four menu items (that are images) that will be contained in a responsive grid. When clicked, I want to have an arrow (in this example it's a box) move to the center of the list-item image that was clicked.

Right now, this javascript is only moving off to the right (I had another version going earlier that moved left/right which is what I want this one to do). Also, the box in this case should always line up centered with the circle that was clicked...despite the width of the screen. That was the big problem...I cannot use pixels or any exact widths.

View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/RevConcept/An4TF/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img id="discover" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img id="design" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img id="develop" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img id="deploy" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.block {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#abc;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    margin:5px;
}

#wrap, #menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}

#menu-wrap {
    text-align:center;
    height:235px;
}

ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}​
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#discover").click(function() {
    $(".block").animate({
        "left": "+=0%"
    }, "slow");
});

$("#design").click(function() {
    $(".block").animate({
        "left": "+=50%"
    }, "slow");
});

$("#develop").click(function() {
    $(".block").animate({
        "left": "+=75%"
    }, "slow");
});

$("#deploy").click(function() {
    $(".block").animate({
        "left": "+=100%"
    }, "slow");
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the box to stay along the bottom like that?  http://jsfiddle.net/An4TF/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close with your initial implementation. I simplified the logic a little bit, adding a class to each of the nav items. The main idea is that you can use pixels, you just need them to be relative to your images. Here I am taking the images location, (specified in any way you wish), and calculating the arrow's position based on that. Then with a little centering, we can find the exact middle of each image.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/An4TF/10/

jQuery:

```
  $(".nav-image").click(function(event){
    var x = $(this).offset().left;

    var img_width = $(this).width();
    var arrow_width = $(".block").width();

    var arrow_x = x + img_width/2 - arrow_width/2;

    $(".block").animate({
        "left": arrow_x
    }, "slow");
  });
```

Fiddle with starting pos: http://jsfiddle.net/An4TF/14/

You can change the selectors to determine witch image you want the arrow to point to initially.

Comment: If I weren't married, I would marry you. THANKS A MILLION!

Comment: One more question...how can I get it to "Start" at the first position...instead of all the way to the left?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to "reset" this script when a user adjusts their browser AND/OR changes their browser resolution? The arrow goes wacky when that happens until it's clicked again...hmmmm.

Comment: You are truly a genius. One last thing (related) but I started a new question because I thought someone else might be searching. Maybe you could have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11679353/1009102