# Hiding overflow of absolutely positioned div disrupts Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, css-position

I got some help with a solution to make this "arrow" align with the middle of the objects above it on click...it was working.

Since then, I have done some more work on the design and needed to set the overflow of the "wrap" div to position:relative in order to hide x-axis overflow of the arrow...that works, but:

Now the alignment has gone off. I can't figure out why as I am no good with jQuery :(

One important note: this site is responsive, and adjusting the browser width is now doing crazy stuff to the arrow position (only since I've changed the wrap to position:relative).

View code here: http://jsfiddle.net/RevConcept/y86RG/5/

Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
<div class="container">                        
        <div class="row">

                <ol class="flexslider-nav">
                    <li class="threecol">
                        <img id="discover" class="btn-workflow" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" alt="#" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="threecol">
                        <img id="design" class="btn-workflow" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" alt="#" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="threecol">
                        <img id="develop" class="btn-workflow" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" alt="#" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="threecol last">
                        <img id="deploy" class="btn-workflow" src="http://nillabean.com/images/circle-225.png" alt="#" />
                    </li>                
                </ol>

            </div><!--end row-->

            <!-- WORKFLOW: DESC. SLIDER -->
            <div class="row">

                <div class="twelvecol last">

                     <div class="arrow-wrap">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                     </div><!--end arrow-wrap -->

                    <div class="flexslider">
                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li>
                                <p>Test Content</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>Test Content</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>Test Content</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p>Test Content</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--end flexslider-->

                </div><!--end col-->

            </div><!--end row-->
```

​

CSS:

```
   .container p {
       color: #fff;
       line-height: 100px;
       background: #000;
       text-align: center;
       margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    .flexslider p {
        margin-top:0px;
        background:transparent;
        color:#000000;
    }

    .flexslider {
        border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
        border-left:1px #000 solid;
        border-right:1px #000 solid;
    }

    h1, h2, h3 {
        text-align:center;
    }

    .flexslider-nav li img {
        display:block;
        margin:0px auto;
    }

    .arrow {
      position:absolute;
      background:transparent url(http://nillabean.com/images/arrow.png) repeat-x bottom center;
      width:2200px;
      height:40px;
    }

    .arrow-wrap {
        position:relative;       
        height:35px;
        border:1px #C00 solid;
    }

​
```

JQUERY:

```
        var start_pos = $("#discover").offset().left + $("#discover").width()/2 - $(".arrow").width()/2;

    $(".arrow").css("left", start_pos);

    $(".btn-workflow").click(function(event){
        var x = $(this).offset().left;

        var img_width = $(this).width();
        var arrow_width = $(".arrow").width();

        var arrow_x = x + img_width/2 - arrow_width/2;

        $(".arrow").animate({
            "left": arrow_x
        }, "slow");
    });
```

IMAGE:

This is ultimately what I'm trying to do...the border and transparency are making this more difficult than just adding s simple arrow.

[image: The finished div and arrow should look like this] 
​

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Links can rot, and people shouldn't have to follow links to help you. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Thanks! I thought about that...I will add now ;)

Comment: @JaredFarrish, HAHA! I can't believe I never noticed that. Thanks ;)

Comment: The positioning is off because of the margin that you added. you're going to have to subtract that from the movement calculation. I'll work on a fiddle.

Comment: I would recommend a re-consideration of your current css. It has major problems when the window is re-sized. Until the css is set, there is no way that we can find a solution for you, as it is dependent on the margin.

Comment: what margin are you referring too?

Comment: If you're talking about the margins on the list-items, I cannot remove them...they are fundamental to my responsive grid. I guess I could compromise my overall design :( I need the overflow in order to use a "border" with a semi-transparent background for the arrow and the div under it (so they seem connected).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y86RG/13/
Will that work? Here's what I have changed

```
.arrow {
  position:absolute;
  background:transparent url(http://nillabean.com/images/arrow.png) repeat-x bottom center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:35px;
}

.arrow-wrap {
    position:relative;       
    height:35px;
    border:1px #C00 solid;
}
```

And in the JS, removed the following line

```
//        $(".arrow").css("left", start_pos);
```